# Persistent program in Go

Tags: go, exec

I'm trying to learn Go, and I thought I'd start with a project I've wanted to do for some time (but which seemed too 'fiddly' to bother with). The essential idea is that I have a program which interacts with the user on stdin/stdout and I'd like to write a new program which interacts with the program in the same way (as if it were a person running the program).

Now the program here is simple, in that it's synchronous: you enter a command, get some output, and then it sits there waiting for the next batch of input. That didn't seem so hard, but I'm having trouble getting this I/O skeleton working.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("e")    // A simple program that echos input until it becomes "exit"

    progin, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Trouble with e's stdout")
        panic(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Trouble starting e")
        panic(err)
    }

    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))

    buf := bufio.NewReader(progin)
    for {
        // Write stuff
        var toProg string
        if (r.Float64() < .1) {
            toProg = "exit"
        } else {
            toProg = fmt.Sprintf("%d", r.Int)
        }
        fmt.Println("Printing: ", toProg)
        cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(toProg + "\n")

        // Read stuff
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // give the program time to generate output

        input, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("I did *not* like that: ", input)
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Received: ", input)

    }
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: For testing, here's source for `e`: http://pastebin.com/59Qc3bxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest issue is you're reassigning the command's Stdin, instead of piping to it.

Here's a working version:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./e") // A simple program that echos input until it becomes "exit"

    progin, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Trouble with e's stdout")
        panic(err)
    }

    progout, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Trouble with e's stdin")
        panic(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Trouble starting e")
        panic(err)
    }

    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))

    buf := bufio.NewReader(progin)
    for {
        // Write stuff
        var toProg string
        if r.Float64() < .1 {
            toProg = "exit"
        } else {
            toProg = fmt.Sprintf("%d", r.Int())
        }
        fmt.Println("Printing: ", toProg)
        progout.Write([]byte(toProg + "\n"))

        // Read stuff
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // give the program time to generate output

        input, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("I did *not* like that: ", input)
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Received: ", input)

    }
}
```

And e.go with a few fixups:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    for {
        buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        input, err := buf.ReadString('\n')

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Echo failed: ", input)
            panic(err)
        }

        if strings.HasPrefix(input, "exit") {
            fmt.Println("Bye!")
            return
        }

        fmt.Print(input)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of reinventing the wheel, everything you want to do can be handled by the `fmt` package, so just use that and add in the extra stuff like the random number checker where it is needed.

Here is an example of how to achieve this easily: http://play.golang.org/p/b9GNovSRFj

And for a quick look, the main functionality of this strategy:

```
var s string
_, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(s)
```

Note that it will not run in the playground due to permission issues, but if you run it locally it should work fine.

Comment: Please include the essence of your code in the answer as well.

Comment: This doesn't spawn an external process at all, I'm not sure how it's connected to my question.